# Problems with login to webpage using Facebook login:

Tags: facebook

My website is: www.askachristianlive.org/forum

In the upper right you will see a Facebook icon that is supposed to allow you to login using your Facebook credentials. Every time I get the following error:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I have changed everything I can think of in the app settings and it still will not work. Can you please tell me what I need to do?

My app domain is set to www.askachristianlive.org

Select how your app integrates with Facebook
Website with Facebook Login
Site URL: http://www.askachristianlive.org

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct appId adn secret etc? (obviously don't post them here). Also what are you using for the login url? Is this correct on your login url. Are you using the built-in $facebook->getLoginUrl() method (if using php) you haven't mentioned any specific languages or SDKs so not sure what you're using. Try adding *.askachristianlive.org to your allowed domains. It

Comment: O boy. I have no idea about any of this. I used one all and it said this would only take minutes. Google login works great because I didn't have to set up anything. But I had to create a Facebook app and as far as I can tell everything should be set up correctly. I copied the keys and pasted them into oneall. Everything checks out. Until you try logging in with Facebook credentials. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: I've not heard of one all. But it sounds like your login url is not being rendered correctly. If you right click on your facebook login link, what is the actual url (e.g. the href attribute)

Comment: This is the url displayed in the Facebook popup window where you are supposed to be able to login: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=788021007891742&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Faskachristianlive.api.oneall.com%2Fsocialize%2Fcallback.html%3Fprovider_connection_token%3Db239e959-cec2-417e-b10f-c9b7ae9db1d3%26oainonce%3Dbe00d56b-b79e-40eb-bd69-915de3bb128b&state=b790cc554ad147f45eaad40251f4fde5&display=popup&scope=email

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the url generated by oneall is askachristianlive.api.oneall.com which most likely isn't in your allowed app domains

See if you can add the above url to your app domains in your app settings list and if that works.

The problem is oneall is another 3rd party on top of a third party (Facebook in this case) so although your app config in facebook matches your domain, it doesn't match the fact that you have to go through oneall. To be honest I'm surprised that oneall haven't highlighted this fact on their website, as these callback urls would never work for facebook otherwise

Comment: Ah, thank you! That solves one problem at least. Now it says I can sign in with Facebook, but when I do, it doesn't seem to take effect, and treats me as though I never signed in. Do you have a fix for this?